# A four-digit square is of the form $aabb$. What's $a^2+b^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

The 5772 [Ulpaniada](http://ulpaniada.macam.ac.il/english/about.asp) included the following question:

> Consider a four digit square number (a number which is the square of a whole number).
> Its digit notation is $aabb$ (the thousands digit is $a$, the hundreds digit is $a$, the tens digit is $b$ and the units digit is $b$).
> What is the value of $a^2+b^2$?

It offered five choices: $51$, $85$, $73$, $65$, and $60$.

$85$ and $65$ are the only choices equal to $a^2+b^2$ for $b\in\{1,4,9,5,6\}$ and $1\le a\le9$. That analysis also shows $aabb$ to be one of $2299$, $7766$, $8811$, and $7744$. Since $11$ goes into $aabb$, so does $11^2$, which eliminates $7766$ and $8811$ (as $11\nmid706$, $11\nmid801$). But I can't seem to narrow it down further, to decide between $7744$ and $2299$ (without, of course, reference to or generation of a list of squares), or by any other means to decide between $85$ and $65$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571582/find-the-four-digit-number

Comment: @labbhattacharjee nice find! Looks like a duplicate. I recommend closure-as-duplicate votes.

Comment: it was tough ask as I answered it:) Anyway, don't miss the link in my comment in the answer

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, oh, that solution (linked to in your comment there) is much simpler! For ease of reference I'll summarize it here for future readers: $11\mid aabb$ so $aabb\in\{33^2,\ldots,99^2\}$ and then test each.

Comment: I found  it after I posted the answer. But the solution in the link involves a little more calculation than my answer.